# Transform 2-dimension data to 3-dimension data for ternary plot with R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, ternary

I have 2-dimension data (**from the lower part of a matrix**):

```
m <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,1,2,2,3),y=c(1,2,3,1,2,1))
#  x y
#1 1 1
#2 1 2
#3 1 3
#4 2 1
#5 2 2
#6 3 1
```

If I plot this, it gives something like this:

```
x
x x
x x x
```

So, I have the `x` and `y` axis. However, I'd like to plot this data in a ternary plot, like this:

```
  x
 x x
x x x
```

I need the `z` axis. It's the same data, but with another axis.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the goal on this. You can use the `ggtern` package to make a ternary plot as follows: `library(ggtern) ; ggtern(m, aes(x = x1, y = x2, z = x3)) + geom_point()` but it isn't very meaningful due to the missing values.

Comment: @NickCriswell I don't have values for `z` axis.

Comment: Not sure if this is a case for a ternary plot unless the third axis, `z`, can be defined in terms of the first two.

Comment: @NickCriswell I modified my post, hope it's more clear

Comment: So essentially you need new X coordinates, but these depend on the Y coordinate?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you want is a ternary plot, though I am not at all sure why you are looking to move the data in this manner if you don't have a z-value. Take a look at this description of [ternary plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_plot) and note that they, by definition, have three variables (and your data only have 2) and they must always sum to a constant (unless you mean yours are missing the last variable, which makes each row sum to some constant that you have not defined in your question?).

If you are just looking to shift the x-values, you can center them for each value of y, though only if the y values are discrete as is the case here. This uses `dplyr` to do the modifications, and `scale`s each set of x values to center around 0 (though it does not modify for standard deviation).

```
m %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  mutate(newX = as.numeric(scale(x, scale = FALSE)) ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = newX, y = y)) +
  geom_point()
```

Gives:

[image]

I'm not sure what information you are getting from doing this, as you lose all ability to compare back to the original x scale this way. Unless you add `color = factor(x)` to the mapping, like this:

[image]

If this is not what you are trying to do (and I rather hope that it is not), please update your question to clarify the output that you are expecting.

On the off chance that what you meant was that there was a `z` column missing which caused each row to sum to a particular constant, here is an example using `ggtern` to plot that, with the assumption that each row sums to 10 units:

```
m %>%
  mutate(z = 10 - (x + y)) %>%
  ggtern(aes(x, y, z)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]